# for each array combine for 3 or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am trying to submit an array of 3 textfileds from my form and then send to my database, table

my form

```
  <input type="hidden" name="itemqt[]" value="<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="itemname[]" id="text-basic" value="<?php echo $item["name"]; ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="itemprice[]" id="text-basic" value="<?php echo $item["price"]; ?>">
```

basically when i attempt to combine two arrays it works

```
foreach (array_combine($_POST['id'], $_POST['itemprice'] ) as $name => $email)

 {

  echo  "";
  //$name . " - " . $email .
  $ocode = $_POST['ocode'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (pid, price,status,method,ocode, quantity) VALUES ('$name','$email','paid','Card','$ocode','$_POST[itemqt]')";

 if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      echo "";
    }
     else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}

}

}

}
```

but when i try to attempt to combine a 3 array, with another field like dis, it fails. i get a syntax error

```
foreach (array_combine($_POST['id'], $_POST['itemprice'], $_POST['itemqt'] ) as $name => $email, $qt)

 {

  echo  "";
  //$name . " - " . $email .
  $ocode = $_POST['ocode'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (pid, price,status,method,ocode, quantity) VALUES ('$name','$email','paid','Card','$ocode','$_POST[itemqt]')";

 if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      echo "";
    }
     else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}

}

}

}
```

please any idea, has someone successfully combined 3 arrays

Comment: the very nature of array_combine makes combining 3 arrays impossible, are you perhaps thinking of array_merge? PHP manual defines both pretty clearly.

Comment: Also, even when you merge all arrays the desired result isn't going to give you what you're trying to get in your foreach loop: `$name => $email`. It's going to give you a number as `$name` and either quantity, name, or price as `$email`

Answer (score 1):

`array_combine` makes result array from 2 arrays - one for keys and another for values. What do you expect by adding third array? It would be added to keys, to values? Where?

What you really need is just a `foreach` loop on some base variable, presumably `$_POST['id']`:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
    // get values from other $_POST variables with the same key as $i
    echo $id, ': ', $_POST['itemprice'][$i], ' => ', $_POST['itemqt'][$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) {
    // get values from other $_POST variables with the same key as $key
    echo $id, ': ', $_POST['itemprice'][$key], ' => ', $_POST['itemqt'][$key];
}
```

And sure, you can check if `$_POST['itemprice'][$key]` or `$_POST['itemqt'][$key]` exist for a certain `$key`

Comment: ok, and i suppose this "$_POST['itemprice'][$i]"  this can be passed into my sql statement

Comment: pls how do i pass the values to my database table, when i try to dump dem in my sql like dis   "$_POST[itemprice][$key]," i get Array[1]
Array[1]

Comment: And what is the output of just `$_POST['itemprice']`?

Comment: i get this Array
Array

Comment: Use `print_r` or `var_dump`

Comment: string(2) " 4" string(2) ": " string(5) "30.00" string(4) " => " string(1) "1"

Comment: Please, check your codes once again. WHat is the real output - `"30.00"` or `Array`?

Comment: what i said initially is when i try to submit to my database table using dis $_POST['itemprice'], i got array in my database